# Why would an Image-based itemRenderer always be visible?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, itemrenderer

Given the following code:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ongoing" id="ongoing" headerText="" width="20">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
            <mx:Image source="logo.jpg" visible="false" />
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

why would the image always be visible?  I know for a fact that data.ongoing is always being set equal to 'False', and I know for a fact that the image is getting this information.  That shouldn't even have anything to do with it, as far as I can tell, but I've been surprised by Flex's framework before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely because Flex recycles its itemrenderers to save memory. Here's [a similar question that was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971455/weird-behaviour-checkboxes-as-itemrenderer-within-flex-datagrid-flex-3/4971867#4971867).

What I would do is override the set data method to set the image's visible value to what it should be.

Comment: Thanks, man!  I just found about the whole recycling thing a little bit ago, and I didn't think about that playing into the graphical representation.

Comment: @Panzercrisis No worries! It's one of the feature of Flex I have a love/hate relationship with. If my answer helps solve your issue, an upvote and/or marking it as the accepted answer would be appreciated. Good luck!

Comment: Interesting, I'm still having trouble setting its visibility depending on whether ongoing is equal to 'True' or not.  This works, for instance, inside of the set data override: text = (value.ongoing == 'False').toString();  But this doesn't: super.visible = (value.ongoing == 'True');  Same if I omit "super.".  How do I do this?