# How can you make a Datagrid's Image-based itemRenderer either visible or not, depending on the value of its row and column in the datagrid?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, itemrenderer

The description is basically the same as the title.  This is a related post I made a little while ago: [Why would an Image-based itemRenderer always be visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959854/why-would-an-image-based-itemrenderer-always-be-visible/11959969#11959969)  Basically the dataField that's being used for the itemRenderer's column in this case is "ongoing", and I want to set the itemRenderer and/or its image to true or false, depending on the value of ongoing in that row.  If the itemRenderer is Label-based, I'm able to set the text to different values, depending on that.  Certain specific properties, like visible, are problematic though.  Documentation I've found so far on using states is very difficult to follow, and I'm not even sure those apply here.  How do I do this?  The current code, by the way is as follows:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ongoing" id="ongoing" headerText="">
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:Image source="logo.jpg">
            <mx:Script>
                <![CDATA[
                    override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                        super.data = value;
                        super.visible = (value.ongoing != 'False');
                    }
                ]]>
            </mx:Script>
        </mx:Image>
    </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

I've also tried working with the set visible override.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make any sense, especially in a Datagrid. If you don't want to display data, filter for it using a collection's filter function. Otherwise you're having empty cells.

Also, you're working against the component live cycle:
Setting visible in data will be called before the component is actually rendered - so there is no effect. If you're using vanilla objects and no classes, changes of the property's value will not have any effects as well.

On a site note: Boolean should be Booleans, no Strings and inline renderers can lead to some scoping issues, that's why i'd recommend using a separate component definition (aka .as or .mxml file).

Comment: We're still displaying a lot of data for the rows where the image isn't going to be shown.  It's just going to be a green dot in the left-most column to mark certain particular rows.  But I don't understand how to make this work, and there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of information out there about it.

Comment: You have to overwrite commitProperties and work with classes to make dataBinding work. It is all based on the "Flex component live cycle", which is documented quite well.

Comment: I have yet to see an actual answer here, Florian.  All I've seen so far is a couple of suggestions about why my approach isn't working and then you just pounding on your chest and trying to let the world know how smart you are.

Comment: The actual answer is given in my down-voted post: "Setting visible in data will be called before the component is actually rendered - so there is no effect." Data will be called/set before the component was added to the display list. So you manipulated the component's state to "visible=false". "visible" is actually false and will be set to true by the component itself after some point it was added to the display list. So you have to ensure the component stays invisible by setting "visible" to false in "commitProperties", not in the data setter. Hope this helps more.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can loosely be found here by gokiさん:

http://www.fxug.net/modules/xhnewbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=2229

At the moment at least, I'm having to actually set the source to either the image or a blank string to get this to work (looked like he was trying to do something slightly different), but it works.

EDIT: These two lines of code replaced where he was messing with the visible property:

```
var property0:SetProperty = new SetProperty(this, "source", "");
var property1:SetProperty = new SetProperty(this, "source", "dot.png");
```